# Applications of non-symmetric bilinear forms?

Tags: linear-algebra, big-list, bilinear-form

There are numerous applications of *symmetric* bilinear forms: They show up in the Hessian matrix in optimisation, for instance. What I'm curious about is where *asymmetric* bilinear forms occur.

I know that the [Fundamental Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_matrix_(computer_vision)) in Computer Vision is one such application.

An asymmetric bilinear form is a map
$$B: U \times V \to k$$
linear in both its arguments, and where $k$ is a field. We will exclude examples where $U = V$ and $B$ is symmetric (i.e. $B(u,v)=B(v,u)$ for all $u, v \in V$).

Comment: @Dr.RichardKlitzing No. That's not even a bilinear form.

Comment: @Dr.RichardKlitzing More obviously wrong (or aggressively pedantic and bad faith) suggestions will make me delete this question. This is why I'm reluctant to post here

Comment: For example, KL divergence.

Comment: @HanceWu KL divergence is not a bilinear form

Comment: Your question is a bit strange. I think $B$ is called a bilinear form only when $U=V$, otherwise it is just called a bilinear map. Also, when $U\ne V$, what do you mean by “symmetric” or “asymmetric”? The expression $B(v,u)$ simply makes no sense at all when $u\in U$ and $v\in V$ are arbitrary.

Comment: A bilinear map $B:U\times V\rightarrow k$ can be identified with a map $B:U\rightarrow V^*$ where $V^*$ is the dual of $V$. In particular, any bilinear map is an operator between $U$ and $V$ and operators between vector spaces are used in multiple instances, does it answer the question?

Comment: @Yanko No. I am looking for examples in applications

Comment: @Yanko I know all this formality. You appear to be dangerously close to saying that $V 
= V^*$, but there is no natural isomorphism between $\operatorname{id}$ and $(-)^*$. It doesn't answer the question

Comment: @user1551 I've looked at Wikipedia, and my definition might be unconventional. I take $U \neq V$ to automatically imply asymmetric. Saying it's "just called a bilinear map" is misleading because the cross product is a bilinear *map* which isn't a bilinear *form* because it doesn't map into $k$.

Comment: I see that my definition of "bilinear form" is unconventional. I might need to edit.

Answer (score 2):

The determinant of two-by-two matrices is a bilinear form, when seen as a function of the two columns of the matrix. It is anti-symmetric.
$$
\Bigl(\pmatrix{v_1, v_2}, \pmatrix{w_1, w_2} \Bigr)\mapsto v_1 w_2 - v_2 w_1.
$$
Any bilinear form is the sum of a symmetric bilinear form and an anti-symmetric bilinear form.

A [symplectic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_vector_space) is a non-degenerate antisymmetric bilinear form that exists on all even dimensional spaces. It occurs in [hamiltonian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) and of course in [symplectic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_geometry).